# Change RadWindow style

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, telerik

How do I modify the style or color of RadWindow? Im using SL4 and Telerik's latest binaries which is compatible with SL4.

I've tried the following, but it is not working.

```
<radNavigation:RadWindow.Resources> 
    <Style x:Key="RadWindowStyleActionGotFocus" TargetType="radNavigation:RadWindow"> 
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter> 
    </Style> 
</radNavigation:RadWindow.Resources> 
<radNavigation:RadWindow.Style> 
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="RadWindowStyleActionGotFocus"/> 
</radNavigation:RadWindow.Style>
```

Comment: Please add detail to your question.  What does your xaml currently look like?  What have your tried? What happened? Be specific about what your problem is.  The more detail you can provide the more likely you'll get the answer you need.

Comment: I have tried following solution but it is not working 

<radNavigation:RadWindow.Resources> 

<Style x:Key="RadWindowStyleActionGotFocus" TargetType="radNavigation:RadWindow"> 

<Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue">

</Setter> 

</Style> 

</radNavigation:RadWindow.Resources> 

<radNavigation:RadWindow.Style> 

<StaticResource ResourceKey="RadWindowStyleActionGotFocus"/> 

</radNavigation:RadWindow.Style>

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to MS Expression Blend, then you can create a new style element by copying the current RadWindow Style.  This will allow you to change the required styles.  Please note that you must specify a key for the style and then set the style attribute using the appropriate static resource